# Huawei E1260 dialer detecting device in 13.04 but not in 13.10

Tags: usb-modem

I am facing a similar problem like many others, but yet different.

I have the dialer working, but it is not able to detect to device to initialize it.

Any solutions? Been at it for a few hours.

I somehow made it work when I was using 13.04, but after upgrading to 13.10 recently, it has stopped detecting the device automatically.

Comment: Can you connect through the network manager?

Comment: It shows "false." Should I change it to true? Restart after doing so?

Comment: Yup the interfaces file shows that where "auto lo" and "iface lo inet loopback" are in separate lines. No sign of enable mobile broadband after restarting.

Comment: Sorry , before installing packages, just see `sudo service network-manager restart` and weather it connects.

Comment: Ok copied n saved. Thanks. I can see the "Enable Mobile Broadband" now and the "Tata Indicom (Photon+)" option. I tried connecting but it doesn't connect. Hence, should I try installing the dialer? Or should I do something else and try to connect from network manager? Thanks

Comment: After unplugging n restarting, the "enable mobile broadband option has disappeared. Hmmm....it's like back to square one.

Comment: Again check `gksudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and see the line `managed=` is `true` or `false`. Try `nmcli nm wwan on && nmcli con up id 'Tata Indicom (Photon+)'`.This is the command to connect via terminal. If not connect, please include the content in terminal while running this command in your question post. Someone with expert knowledge will help. Also try with: Open the application Network Connections and delete present "Tata Indicom (Photon+)" Profile and make a new.

Comment: Ok will do. Thanks for trying. Much appreciated.

Comment: Btw, once you turn on "Enable Mobile Broadband" the device should get registered with the CDMA Network first and then we should attempt to connect through Tata Photon+ right? The device isn't registering with the CDMA network in the first place which explains why it isn't connecting.

Comment: did you created the new profile? you can follow [this](http://allfreeubuntu.blogspot.com/2013/11/how-to-create-network-connection-in.html). You need to add the wcdma or gprs depending on the way you registered with tata.